# Is it possible to run a PHP file which doesn't contain any html?

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to run a PHP file which doesnt contain any html?

I have a form, from which I want to submit data to a database. If I were to have the submit buttons `action` property set to a php file which solely deals with data submission, and then have a redirect on this page to the next *visible* webpage, would this work?

My reason for asking is I have quite a few different forms, some of which use the same submission code. If I were to have all this on one page and then use conditional logic to determine where the data came from (thus being able to determine what data was submitted and which page to load next) it would make my webpages much more readable, and the submission code much more re-usable.

Comment: It is possible. Every php code will be executed per request, no matter if theres output or not.

Comment: Yes... in fact none of my PHP files actually contain any HTML.  I use templates.

Comment: @dognose I agree with you and the process describe in the question seems to be a kind of MVC design pattern. So if you want to know more you could search MVC pattern on google

Comment: Yes, it's most certainly possible and more often than not it's the way web applications are built. A majority of hired programmers generally separate out their code from their underlying html via templating engines of some sort or their own methodology. Look up MVC architecture.

Comment: `<?php echo 'no html'; ?>` yup it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can take care of all kinds of things behind the scenes.  That's the basic meaning of *server-side scripting*.  So yes -- HTML or on-screen presentation are not necessarily in the code everywhere.

Comment: So i presume a typical webpage would have alot of `include` lines to include different bits of code contained in different PHP files? Does it stand to reason that a typical webpage would have many, many small PHP files rather than just a few bigger ones so the code is re-usable in different scenarios? Sorry if this sounds very basic, im trying to teach myself, and havent seen any 'professional' website source code so have no reference!!

Comment: @Giovanni perhaps then you should look one of the many open source projects to see how its done.

Comment: @Dagon Didnt think any such thing existed! any idea where I might find one?

Comment: you have seriously not heard of open source software ?

Comment: Of course ive heard of open source software, It didnt cross my mind that there would be opensource websites that I could look at the source code to see how things are put together. This site is for learning and asking questions; although my original question mightve seemed quite simple, im not sure it warranted the 3 sarcastic comments. Everybodys a beginner at some point....

Comment: @Giovanni -- Yes, yes, and yes. Your question is pretty natural, but a bit un-specific to really work on StackOverflow. You will find it takes a huge amount of learning and exploration to become productive in PHP. Good luck and I hope it goes well!